# Formatting JSON from SQL Table Results in C#

Tags: c#, sql, json, serialization

Im trying to format JSON in c# in the following manner. Lets say I have the following table

`col1  col2 col3 col4

    comA  1    2    3

    comB  4    5    6

    comC  7    8    9`

I would like my JSON Output to be like so

`[{
    name: 'comA',
    data: [1,2,3]

    }, {
    name: 'comB',
    data: [4,5,6]
    }, {
    name: 'comC',
    data: [7,8,9]
    }]`

I have the following code

```
public class ChartLoc
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Data{ get; set; }
}

public void myFunc(){
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                List<String> _Category = new List<String>();
                List<String> _Data = new List<String>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {


                    _Data.Add(reader["col2"].ToString() + ',' + reader["col3"].ToString() + ',' + reader["col4"].ToString());

                    if (reader["store"] != DBNull.Value) _Category.Add(reader["col1"].ToString());
                }
                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                cl.Category = jss.Serialize(_Category); 
                cl.Data = jss.Serialize(_Data);
            }
        }
    }         
}
```

although this output will give me

cl.Category = ['comA','comB','comC']
cl.Data = ['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8,9']

Comment: have you looked at any of the links on the lower right hand side of this page under `Related`? here is a link from one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880171/sql-server-table-to-json?rq=1

Comment: Not quite what I want, I've seen this post already. Not looking for creating stored procedure. Looking to do this in C# only. I have no read/write privlages on SQL(not true but lets pretend) I just want to format the JSON in CSHARP the way I mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have output like `[{ name: 'comA', data: [1,2,3] }, { name: 'comB', data: [4,5,6] }, { name: 'comC', data: [7,8,9] }]`, you will need to serialize your object differently. Since you want a list of numbers in your JSON and not a string, you will need to represent the numbers as a `List` in your class definition. Something like this should work:

```
[Serializable]
public class ChartLoc
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<int> Data { get; set; }
}

public string myFunc()
{
    string jsonString = "";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<ChartLoc> _ChartLoc = new List<ChartLoc>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ChartLoc chart = new ChartLoc();
                    chart.Data.Add(int.Parse(reader["col2"].ToString()));
                    chart.Data.Add(int.Parse(reader["col3"].ToString()));
                    chart.Data.Add(int.Parse(reader["col4"].ToString()));

                    if (reader["store"] != DBNull.Value) 
                        chart.Category = reader["col1"].ToString();
                    _ChartLoc.Add(chart);
                }
                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                jsonString = jss.Serialize(_ChartLoc);
            }
        }
    }
    return jsonString;         
}
```

Comment: EXCELLENT! much appreciated. This is the answer I was looking for. CHEERS!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single JSON string containing a set of category/data pairings you will want to serialize a single object.  I would suggest a list of ChartLoc and then serialize the list.

In addition, if your Data object is a string it will be serialized as a string (i.e. "1,2,3" instead of [1,2,3]).  If you really want to fix that, you will want a collection of ints.

```
public class ChartLoc
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<int> Data { get; set; }
}
...
var chartLocs = new List<ChartLoc>();
chartLocs.Add(new ChartLoc { Category = "comA", Data = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 } });
chartLocs.Add(new ChartLoc { Category = "comB", Data = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 } });
chartLocs.Add(new ChartLoc { Category = "comC", Data = new List<int> { 7, 8, 9 } });

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jss.Serialize(chartLocs);
```

The resulting JSON is much more similar to what you are seeking...

> [{"Category":"comA","Data":[1,2,3]},{"Category":"comB","Data":[4,5,6]},{"Category":"comC","Data":[7,8,9]}]

Comment: This is GREAT, short simple and sweet. This is exactly what I was looking for. THANKS!