# Converting SQL table data to JSON automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I am looking to have my data in JSON format from SQL server database.Is there any API available for it ? Basically I need it for demo purposes only.

Some thing like [this Looks relevant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYElY4ewq_o&feature=youtu.be) but again I am not sure how is that being used here. I have apache installed.

Can I get some directions on it or may be some other API relatively easier to use ?

Comment: i faound an article which could be helpfull: https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/26/sql-server-json-to-table-and-table-to-json/ maybe it helps you to choose a way

Answer (score 0):

A Web API might be a good choice. I recommend using the Database First approach if you already had the Database: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1.
Well, a better tutorial can be found here: http://tomislavbabicnet.blogspot.com/2013/03/build-application-using-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Comment: Thank you but that somewhat looks specific to .NET ? I Need something that will just give me a URL where I can have all my table data in JSON format so that it can be used for my work.

Comment: Asking so as I have never worked with .NET and neither do  I have VS installed at my end.

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/ pretty much uses JSon as it's native storage. It has nothing to do with SQL Server though.

Comment: What do you mean by "give me a URL where I can have all my table data in JSON format" Do you mean you want a URL that points you at some database code that converts a table to JSON, or do you need that as part of the entire solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it in the sqlserver.

Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880171/sql-server-table-to-json). It will solve the purpose.